# Using Cython for libimobiledevice functionality in Python

Tags: python, ios, cython, libimobiledevice

I am working on a project that uses libimobiledevice to access information from iOS devices. Up to now, I have been using a compiled Windows version ([here](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/releases/tag/v1.3.14)) which has .exe files which I can use to do stuff like getting device name or info. I would like to have this same functionality through Python, but I have struggling to find and Python bindings which are working for me. The [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/libimobiledevice) repo includes "Cython based bindings for Python". Is this what I'm looking for to use libimobiledevice in my Python project? If so, how do I use these Cython files in the same way I would use ideviceinfo or idevicename from the binaries of the libimobiledevice-win32 project? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It probably is what you're looking for. When you install it with the instructions given it should give you a compiled Python module (the file ending with .pyd on Windows). You should be able to import it like any other Python module, and then use `dir()` to figure out what interface it has

Comment: Thanks, this has clarified it for me. However, I don't know how to install it on Windows without using the provided builds of libimobiledevice which only contain exe and dll files. To get the compiled Python module it seems I would need more than these builds provide.